# Do we have to adhere to legacy browsers for answers to questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, answer-quality

There is a debate going on the the [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741879/561731) about support of certain JavaScript features in legacy browsers.

Do we **have to** give an answer that adheres to all legacy browsers?

Because if that is so, I know many many answers that do not give a solution for Internet Explorer 1.0...

[image: Internet Explorer 1.0 (right off Google)]

Comment: JScript was added first in IE3.0 though :------)

Comment: If a question explicitly states the level of browser support required, then I answer accordingly, unless the requirements are extremely contrived (although there have been... [exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10559204/106224)).

Comment: But I want to use LocalStorage in IE 6 :(

Comment: @BenBrocka step1) Obtain the packaging for IE6 (over sized box with a tiny little paper sleeve cd in it). step2) open the box. step3) place items in the box. step4) bask in your IE6 localStorage. :)

Comment: Meh, mosiaic is where its at. It even runs on modern copies of linux. Javascript? GET OFF MY LAWN.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Short answer:

## NO

Long(er) answer:

## NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO,

but in my personal opinion it is always nice to inform the user if the code does not work in any specific release (worth noting). So if it fails in IE6, who cares... if it does not work in safari or IE7... well I wouldn't go so far as to provide them with those solutions, rather mention "Hey, this fails in IE7. If IE7 is a concern then you will have to do a little research into how to make it work there as well.".

I think this is completely fair, the OP has his answer, and also has a good starting point on what to search for compatibility concerns.

Comment: the huge ***but!!!*** in this is; if the question specifically outlines browser support. then you should answer accordingly.

Comment: +1. As I now comment (because I feel unsecure, probably), *"As Google halted the support of IE9 in GMail, I can halt the support of IE8 in SO"*.